# How to remove disconnected sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am using a socket server program which is accepting more than 1000 clients concurrently. There are few things

1. Client device make a connection to the server.
2. Sending data every 10 seconds without disconnection.
3. Client device is not concerned about any acknowledgment. Just sending data every 10 seconds and then forget.
4. Server knows the data format which client is sending.

There are few questions...

1. How to receive data from client without disconnection (unless client disconnects itself)?
2. I am also updating no of clients connected in a file. It seems no of clients are always increasing (some time decreasing also but increase rate is much higher). How to keep connected clients count more accurate?

Here is the code...

```
 public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
   // private static DataTable dtServiceId = General.GetAllServiceID();
    private static int numconnections;
    private static int disconnected;

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0], GlobalVariable.ListenPort);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {

            listener.Bind((EndPoint)ipEndPoint);
            listener.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);

            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();
                try
                {
                    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

                 allDone.WaitOne();    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {

            allDone.Set(); 
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = ((Socket)ar.AsyncState).EndAccept(ar);

            Interlocked.Increment(ref numconnections);


       // Writing no of clients in a file

            StateObject stateObject = new StateObject();
            stateObject.workSocket = handler;

            handler.BeginReceive(stateObject.buffer, 0,stateObject.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), stateObject);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        string content="";
        StateObject stateObject = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = stateObject.workSocket;
        try
        {
            int count = handler.EndReceive(ar);
            if (!handler.Connected || count<=0)
            {
                CloseConnection(handler);

                return;
            }


            stateObject.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stateObject.buffer, 0, count));

            content = (stateObject.sb).ToString().Trim();
            stateObject.sb.Clear();
            if (content != "")
            {

               // Doing data insertion
            }
            handler.BeginReceive(stateObject.buffer, 0, stateObject.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), stateObject);

        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {

            CloseConnection(handler);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            CloseConnection(handler);

        }
    }

    private static void CloseConnection(Socket handler)
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref numconnections);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref disconnected);
       // Writing no of clients in a file

        handler.Dispose();
    }
```